# Getting webcam to work on Virtualbox with Linux

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, webcam

I am trying to enable my webcam. Both my guest and host OS are running ArchLinux x86_64. I have followed these steps:

1. Downloaded Virtualbox Extension Pack from virtualbox.org.
2. Added the user to the vboxusers and re-logged in.
3. Enabled USB 2.0 from the USB option from VM settings.
4. Added my Logitech C270 webcam.

---

Now when I launch the virtual machine, and run applications like cheese or visit sites like https://webcamtests.com/, the webcam turns on, the green LED on the camera lights up. But the image is completely blank.

---

System details:

- Host:

1. VirtualBox Version 6.1.18 r142142
2. Kernel:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.10.16-xanmod1-cacule-1-cacule (souravgoswami@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35.1) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat, 20 Feb 2021 17:39:12 +0000
```

3. vboxmanage list webcams

```
Video Input Devices: 2
.3 "Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate"
/dev/video2
.4 "Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate"
/dev/video3
```

I also ran this command:

```
$ vboxmanage controlvm "Archlinux" webcam attach /dev/video2
$ vboxmanage controlvm "Archlinux" webcam attach /dev/video3
```

4. Webcam list:

```
$ vboxmanage controlvm "Archlinux" webcam list
/dev/video2
/dev/video3
```

- Guest:

1. Kernel:

```
$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 5.10.4-xanmod1-cacule-1-cacule (souravgoswami@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35.1) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat, 02 Jan 2021 02:50:59 +0000
```

2. Output from lsusb:

```
$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

3. Output from `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
UVC Camera (046d:0825) (usb-0000:00:0b.0-1):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

If I use ffmpeg to capture the camera, same behaviour, the camera turns on, but nothing is recorded (can't play the video file).

How do I run my webcam with VirtualBox?

Edit:

Added the laptop's integrated camera as well, which also has the same behaviour. The white indicator LED lights up, but no video stream.